XML schema includes schema without taget Namespace compile error in C#
I have a shared XML schema which has not namespace declared department.xsd
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
            version="1-0">
    
    <xs:complexType name="Department">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name"/>
            <xs:element name="Manager"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>

And I want to import Department.xsd in Company.xsd which has the namespace MainNameSpace
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="MainNameSpace"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:m="MainNameSpace" <!--New NameSpace-->
           targetNamespace="MainNameSpace"
           elementFormDefault="unqualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:import schemaLocation="Department.xsd" namespace="MainNameSpace"/> <!--Not working-->

    <!--<xs:import schemaLocation="Department.xsd"/> Not working-->
    <!--<xs:include schemaLocation="Department.xsd"/> Not working-->


    <xs:element name="company" type="Company"/>

    <xs:complexType name="Company">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Department" type="m:Department"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>


However when I compile the schema in C#, I got error "'Type 'MainNameSpace:Department' is not declared.'". From what I read, include another schema without namespace will use the root namespace for the imported schema, but why MainNameSpace:Department cannot be found?
    var schema = new XmlSchemaSet();

    schema.Add(null, Path.Combine(baseDirectory, "Department.xsd"));
    schema.Add(null, Path.Combine(baseDirectory, "Company.xsd"));

    schema.Compile();


In general you should use xs:include to incorporate a schema document for the same target namespace, and xs:import to incorporate a schema document for a different target namespace.
However, there is a feature called "chameleon include" which allows a schema document with target namespace N to xs:include a no-namespace schema S, in which case all the declarations in S are treated as being in the namespace N. You appear to be using this feature here. This will move the Department type into the namespace MainNameSpace, which means that you need to write type="m:Department" when referencing it, and to add xmlns:m="MainNameSpace" to the xs:schema element.

Thanks @MichaelKay, I will received the same error after adding xmlns:m="MainNameSpace". I have updated the code in the question.

Sorry, but changing the question after receiving an answer is just terribly confusing for anyone trying to work out what's going on (including me). Adding to your question, leaving the original intact, is sometimes OK, but modifying the code in a way that invalidates existing answers is not. Start a new thread.

yeah it is messy. I have created anther thread with different solutions I have tried, please take a look, thanks  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79002724/xml-schema-includes-schema-without-namespace-compile-error-in-c-sharp
